# Select records from a table where two columns are not present in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have Table1:

```
Id      Program Price   Age
12345   ABC     10      1
12345   CDE     23      3
12345   FGH     43      2
12346   ABC     5       4
12346   CDE     2       5
12367   CDE     10      6
```

and a Table2:

```
ID      Program BestBefore
12345   ABC     2
12345   FGH     3
12346   ABC     1
```

I want to get the following Table,

```
Id      Program  Price  Age
12345   CDE      10     1
12346   CDE      2      5
12367   CDE      10     6
```

I.e get the rows from the first table where the ID+Program is not in second table. I am using MS SQL Server express 2012 and I don't want to add any columns to the original databases. Is it possible to do without creating temporary variables?

Comment: What have you tired?  `not exists`, `not in`, `outer join / null` check -- lots of ways to do this...

Comment: Not in. But how to specify two columns?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Several ways to do this, here's one using `not exists`:

```
select *
from table1 t1
where not exists (
    select 1
    from table2 t2 
    where t1.id = t2.id and t1.program = t2.program
)
```

Comment: Could you pleas explain what select 1 does?

Comment: @Morpheus -- `not exists` does not care what field is selected -- hence `select 1` or `select *` (different than `not in`).  This produces a `correlated subquery` -- checking for `id` and `program` already existing.

Answer (score 6):

One possible variant is to use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    Table1.*
FROM
    Table1
    LEFT JOIN Table2
        ON  Table1.ID = Table2.ID
        AND Table1.Program = Table2.Program
WHERE
    Table2.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Is this query more or less efficient than the accepted answer (with the where not exists subquery)?

Comment: @samlaf, you need to try both variants with your dataset, your hardware, your version of SQL Server and measure their relative performance. It is likely that both variants would produce the same execution plan, i.e. have the same performance, but you need to test it.